# For a simple closed plane curve, is it possible to find a line satisfying following?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

I am currently reading do Carmo's Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces, and I got stuck on page 33. Here, the author tries to prove that for a postively oriented simple closed curve $\alpha(t)$ and the area $A$ bounded by $\alpha(t)$, $A = -\int_{a}^{b} y(t)x'(t) \, dt$ holds. He first proves for special cases (known as elementary regions) and then generalizes.

In this part, author mentions that for this curve $\alpha(t)$, there exists a straight line $E$ such that the distance $\rho(t)$ of $\alpha(t)$ to this line is a functino with finitely many critical point (which means, $\rho'(t)  = 0$ at there). However, for me, it seems that this argument is false even if we assume $C^{1}$.

Does anyone can prove this statement, or provide other good approach to prove the area formula?

*Edited : I am aware of Green's theorem and the book suggests Stokes' theorem for alternative proof. However, I am rather curious about the argument of finding such straight line $E$.

Comment: Yes. It's an application of Green's Theorem which is in every calculus book. This is the line integral $-\oint_C y\,dx$, where $C$ is the boundary of the region.

Comment: Actually, I am aware of Green's Theorem and I expect that would be true. I am rather curious about the existence of the straight line $E$

Comment: The result is true for $C^1$ functions. It is a consequence of Sard's Theorem (see Guillemin and Pollack, for example) that for almost every unit vector $a\in\Bbb R^2$, the function $f(x)=a\cdot x$ on the curve will have only finitely many critical points. (Such a function is called a Morse function.)

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply! Now it is clear why the proof is omitted. I think it surely exceeds the range of this book... As a final question, then does the statement (regarding line $E$) holds even if the curve is only differentiable? I thought that if a curve is constructed by joining graphs of $y = x^{2}sin 1/x^{3}$ would become a counterexample...

Comment: I suspect you're quite right on that!

Comment: The definition of differentiable curve in this text assumes that each of the component functions are infinitely differentiable, so certainly $C^1$.